# How do I connect to a Firebird SQL Database Using MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, firebird

I am trying to connect to a Firebird SQL database using MS Access. I have the following code:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLCmd As String
Dim sSQL As String

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=Firebird DSN SITEDB_Local;Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=localhost:C:\Application\Data\MNEMBA_LIVE.PDB;CHARSET=NONE;;UID=SYSDBA;Client=C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll;"
cn.Open

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Set Me.Recordset = rs

Do Until rs.EOF

CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM INVENTORY"

rs.MoveNext

Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

errbox:
If Err.Number > 0 Then

MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

> Compile Error
>
> Invalid Use of Me keyword

What is causing this? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure your problem has to do with connecting to Firebird. The error suggests that what you are doing with `Me` is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Are you using this code in a normal module? If so, you can't use `Me`

Comment: Yes, I am running it in a normal Access module. How would I then change the code in order to return the select statement?

Comment: Return it as what? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Also https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/compile-error-invalid-use-of-me-keyword.958060/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/invalid-use-of-me-keyword

Comment: you may also get some ideas fro mthis tutorial, however it targets VB not VBA so there might be more differences than it seems: https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/examples/example_02.html

Comment: Also, copying example code that uses ADODB (e.g., for Excel) might not be the best choice for module code in Access, where DAO is generally preferred over ADODB.

Comment: @GordThompson as far as i understand, DAO is a wrapper over ODBC, while ADO is a wrapper over OLE-DB. So it depends what is chosen as the primary Firebird-connecting library. Would it be ODBC then DAO is more natural choice. But i am very reserved about Firebird ODBC driver - the releases timetable speaks volumes.

Comment: I think there is a mixup here...if the code resides in a module then you cannot use the Me keyword..Me refers to the hosting object when the code runs from a form or a report..

Comment: Thanks John. I was hoping to achieve the result from a module but my skills are coming a little short. I have reverted to a pass through query in Access that solves my problem